# Create a black RGBA image in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image, numpy

I would like to make a black image in RGBA ([0-255, 0-255, 0-255, 0-255]) in Python.
I am trying to do this with numpy.

I have tried the following:

```
arr = 255 * np.ones((height, width), 4), np.uint8)
arr = 0 * np.ones((height, width), 4), np.uint8)
arr = np.zeros((height, width), 4), np.uint8)

arr = np.full((height, width), [0, 0, 0, 255])
```

They all produce a white image, except the last one, that one doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `arr = np.full((height, width, 4), [0, 0, 0, 255])`

Comment: Or `arr = np.zeros((height, width, 4)) + [0, 0, 0, 255] `